# Clipping the width of a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have a transparent ListView on top a VideoView, but the rows are right now taking up the entire width of the screen. I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce this. My XML looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/RelativeScreen"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <VideoView
   android:id="@+id/VideoWindow"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  </VideoView>
  <TextView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Java code is:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, android.R.id.list, a_list));

// Get an object for the list
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        InitiatePlayback(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the textview width and height to match_parent set to wrap_content.

```
 <TextView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/VideoWindow"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </VideoView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This moved my video window down, so it's just playing in a small rectangle @ the bottom of the page (no longer full screen). And the listview is still being displayed across the entire width of the screen (just that it's now right justified)